# programmatically redirect or build URL in React-admin

Tags: react-admin

I'm on React-admin and I'm trying to redirect to the edit view on an "event" click.
To let you imagine better, I'm doing a calendar with events, and the render of event can't be a button. Is there a way to have a hook or a regular func to do this ?
My second option is to build the url and push with connected-react-router. But I don't find a way to it properly. I can do it myself converting char, but I'm sure there is something to do what I want and I can't find it...

Thx all !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'

const history = useHistory()
history.push('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just like if I was pushing with connected-react-router. The problem is still here, how can I build my URL properly...
For now, I just did :

```js
    const redirect = useRedirect();
    redirect(`myResource/${event.id.replace(/\//g, "%2F")}`);
```

I'm replacing IRI slashes with "%2F" to make redirect works, but I really don't like it...